# Sharing a State Array

Tags: javascript, react-native

Have kinda a unique question, in my code I have a listener to a database that loads down objects into an array.

All I do when I load it in is

```
AddObject(obj){
   this.setState({
     Data: [...this.state.Data, obj]
   });
}
```

Pretty simple. However this listener function, there is no exact time when need data will be added. When I go to use that Data sent in Data, I went to pull it out of the Data Array, however I am worried if I try copying data out of the array, or removing the "seen" data, I will get weird behaivor if my listener function triggers and I try adding data to the array at the same time.

Is there some sort of a way to do this? I guess you could call this a shared resource

Ideally, I would have something like this:

```
loadDataIN(){

var LengthToGrab = this.state.Data.length;
//we need to remove this length, now any new data will be added to index 0

}
```

Does this make sense? basically I am trying to figure out the best way to remove data from this array, and not have to worry about overwritting, or losing data. Maybe some sort of processing que

Comment: JavaScript is synchronous. There are no "interrupts" while a block of code is running.

Comment: thats a good point, so in this scenario that listener function couldn't run at the same time i was accessing the data? correct

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

From [official doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> setState() enqueues changes to the component state and tells React
>   that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the
>   updated state.

You don't need to worry that two kinds of situation would have conflict in the same time.
`setState()` enqueues the pending state before the changes be rendered.

In fact, no matter how mechanism be implemented, React is a framework of JavaScript which is working on a model [event-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Event_loop).

So if you want to pull out the data from `this.state.Data`:

```
loadDataIN(){
   this.setState(function(prevState, props) {
     // this.fetchData = prevState.Data;         
     return {
       Data: []
     };
   });
}
```